# Subtract N elements array matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, subtraction

I need to subtract from an array the last N values. Specifically, I have an array with labels that represents human postures and I'm able to calculate the amount of labels to subtract (from the queue..)

I write this code:

```
NUM_POSTURE_TO_SUBTRACT = length(POSTURES_ARRAY)-NUM_POSTURE_MAX;  
 POSTURE_ARRAY = POSTURE_ARRAY(:,1:end-NUM_POSTURE_TO_SUBTRACT);
```

but I have an eeror: `Undefined function or variable "POSTURE_ARRAY"`.

Please, help me!

Comment: are you sure you have POSTURE_ARRAY and POSTURES_ARRAY sorted out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because you are using *POSTURE_ARRAY*` instead of *POSTURE**S**_ARRAY* - missing S. Try the following should work.

```
NUM_POSTURE_TO_SUBTRACT = length(POSTURES_ARRAY)-NUM_POSTURE_MAX;  
POSTURE_ARRAYS = POSTURE_ARRAY(:,1:end-NUM_POSTURE_TO_SUBTRACT);
```

Comment: How does your answer contribute anything new?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting an error that `POSTURE_ARRAY` doesn't exist as a variable, likely because you used `POSTURES_ARRAY` in the first line (Note the S before the '_').

try:

```
POSTURES_ARRAY = POSTURES_ARRAY(:,1:NUM_POSTURE_MAX);
```